# swing object in front of other objects

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, paintcomponent

I've heard that swing is double buffered by default. I'm not trying to have swing double buffered. I am using double buffering and I want to add some swing objects(right now just a JButton added to a JPanel that is added to the JFrame).

The problem is calling frame's paint, repaint or paintComponents methods after I render other stuff erases the visuals of the other stuff. Calling the methods before rendering other stuff causes other stuff to be in front of the swing objects(right now just a JButton). Doing the same directly to JPanel seems to have no effect.

I believe I need a way to paint Jframe or the JPanel added to it without its default background(gray) which causes the window to become blank when set to Color(0,0,0,0).

```
public void paint() {
    // uses double buffering system.
    do {
        do {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) bufferStrategy.getDrawGraphics();
            g2d.fillRect(0, 0, frame.getWidth(), frame.getHeight());
            try {// frame.paintComponents(g2d); // calling it here draws buttons to behind of the object
                rendering(g2d); // I draw other objects in this method
                // frame.paintComponents(g2d);// calling it here makes other objects disappear

        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
            g2d.dispose();
            } while (bufferStrategy.contentsRestored());
        bufferStrategy.show();
     } while (bufferStrategy.contentsLost());
}// method end
```

This is how I set up my button :

```
private void setUpGUI() {
    panel = new JPanel();

    LayoutManager layout = new FlowLayout();
    panel.setLayout(layout);
    panel.setOpaque(false);//this does not seems to have any effect
    panel.setBackground(Color.yellow);//this does not seems to have any effect. this is just for testing

    JButton but1 = new JButton("but1"); 

    panel.add("but1", but1);
    frame.add(panel);

}
```

edit:
This is the workaround/fix:

new paint method:

```
public void paint() {
    // uses double buffering system.
    do {
        do {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) bufferStrategy.getDrawGraphics();
            g2d.fillRect(0, 0, frame.getWidth(), frame.getHeight());
            try {
                frame.paint(g2d); 

        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
            g2d.dispose();
            } while (bufferStrategy.contentsRestored());
        bufferStrategy.show();
     } while (bufferStrategy.contentsLost());
}// method end
```

I've overridden panel's paint method:

```
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            Main.main().rendering(g2d);

            super.paint(g);
            g.dispose();
            g2d.dispose();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Then you should overwrite [`update(Graphics)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#update-java.awt.Graphics-) and prevent swing from clearing your component

Comment: @msrd0 I've tried it. Now yellow background of the panel is showing. I've set panel.setOpaque(false). After that only my button was showing and other objects were lost beneath the gray background

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to create your own BufferStategy!!!

If you want to do custom painting the override the paintComponent() method of a JPanel and then add the panel to the frame. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and examples.

You can then still add components to this panel the same way you do for any other panel. The layout manager of the panel will position the components.

```
panel.setOpaque(false);
panel.setBackground(Color.yellow);
```

The setBackground(...) does nothing because you said the panel is not opaque, which means the background of the parent component will be painted.

```
 panel.add("but1", but1);
```

That is not how you add a component to the panel. The proper method to use is:

```
panel.add(but1);
```

since your panel is using a FlowLayout there is no need to specify a constraint.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Why is BufferStrategy is not necessary? I have moving pictures in the program other than jpanel. 
According to link you have given : `paint() invokes paintComponent().
If ui is non-null, paintComponent() invokes ui.update().
If the component's opaque is true, ui.update() fills the component's background and invokes ui.paint().
ui.paint() renders the content of the component.`   
I did `panel.setOpaque(false)` I've overridden update methods of frame and panel(to do nothing) but some gray(neither panel's nor frame's background Color) background clears other objects

Comment: `Why is BufferStrategy is not necessary?` - Swing is double buffered by default. `I've overridden update methods` - you should NOT override the update() methods, that is old AWT code and is not used in Swing. Read the tutorial and post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) demonstrating the problem if you need more help. Your verbal description of the problem is not enough to give a specific answer which is why I just gave you a general answer.

Comment: I've fixed it(see the edited code in the question) but I'm confused. I've overridden panel's paint and called render from there and it worked but painting was slow. I am painting some tiles and when tiles moved they misaligned till they stopped moving. There weren't such a problem before so I used buffer strategy. My question is: if buffer strategy is not necessary how come not using it slows painting and causes visual errors? Visual artifacts were reduced but not fixed completely by frame.createBufferStrategy(2). It was fixed by the new paint() method http://postimg.org/image/r7w8qb217/ it

Comment: `I've overridden panel's paint` - did you read the tutorial or my answer? Both say you should be overriding paintComponent(). Also, you should not be disposing the Graphics object. That object is used by all the components of the frame. I don't know why you have problems based on a few lines of code.

Comment: I've read the tutorial but couldn't make it work with overriding paintcomponents. Anyways thanks for your time.